# I have requests installed, but I am still getting the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' error

Tags: python

I did pip freeze, and found requests, therefore I have requests, but I am getting an error saying

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

I just installed Python 3.9.2, and Python 3.8 is still on my computer. (Stating this in case it's a contributing factor to my problem.)

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure requests was installed in the correct python install, you can do `python3.9 -mpip list | grep requests` to check if requests is installed for python3.9, if it doesn't show up you can use `python3.9 -mpip install requests` to install it. (the error might be the pip command is the wrong python instances pip command)

Comment: Also, if you're using `pip install` on most systems that installs packages for python2 where you would need to using `pip3 install` to install packages for python3.

Comment: @Hayden I would think even better than that would be todo: `python<version> -mpip` (for example: `python3.9 -mpip`), so you can control the exact version pip installs for